# AEM 6.3 - Creating Event handler using OSGi R6 annotations

Tags: java, osgi, aem, sling

I have created an Event handler by following https://github.com/nateyolles/aem-osgi-annotation-demo/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/nateyolles/aem/osgiannotationdemo/core/listeners/SampleOsgiResourceListener.java and it works fine. However, I get the warning "The field SlingConstants.TOPIC_RESOURCE_ADDED is deprecated". I did some searching and found this thread :https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2325819

Here are the challenges that I am facing:

1) I want to create a separate configuration interface for my event handler. I tried this and it isn't working

```
package com.aem.sites.interfaces;

import org.apache.sling.api.SlingConstants;
import org.osgi.service.event.EventConstants;
import org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations.AttributeDefinition;
import org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations.AttributeType;
import org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations.ObjectClassDefinition;

@ObjectClassDefinition(name = "Temperature Listener Configuration")
public @interface TemperatureListenerConfiguration {

    @AttributeDefinition(
            name = EventConstants.EVENT_FILTER,
            description = "Configurable paths for temperature event listener",
            type = AttributeType.STRING
            )
    String getPaths() default "/content/aemsite/en/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/banner";

    @AttributeDefinition(
            name = EventConstants.EVENT_TOPIC,
            description = "Event types",
            type = AttributeType.STRING
            )
    String[] getEventTypes() default  {SlingConstants.TOPIC_RESOURCE_ADDED,SlingConstants.TOPIC_RESOURCE_CHANGED, SlingConstants.TOPIC_RESOURCE_REMOVED};

}

package com.aem.sites.listeners;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Activate;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Modified;
import org.osgi.service.event.Event;
import org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler;
import org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations.Designate;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.aem.sites.interfaces.TemperatureListenerConfiguration;

@Component(immediate=true,
service=EventHandler.class,
configurationPid = "com.aem.sites.listeners.EventHandler")
@Designate(ocd=TemperatureListenerConfiguration.class)
public class TemperaturePropertyListener implements EventHandler{

     private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        logger.info("*********************Event handler*****************************");

    }

    @Activate
    @Modified
    public void activate(TemperatureListenerConfiguration config) {
        //config.getPaths();
        logger.info("**************************TemperaturePropertyListener******************activate**********************");
    }

}
```

I also want the solution for SlingConstants deprecated issue. Not sure  if ResourceChangeListener is the answer to my problem and if yes then how everything is going to work together in the code.

Thanks in advance

===============================
Latest Code

```
package com.aem.sites.listeners;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.sling.api.resource.observation.ResourceChange;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.observation.ResourceChangeListener;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Activate;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Modified;
import org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations.Designate;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.aem.sites.interfaces.TemperatureListenerConfiguration;


@Component(immediate=true,
service=ResourceChangeListener.class,
configurationPid = "com.aem.sites.listeners.TemperaturePropertyListener")
@Designate(ocd=TemperatureListenerConfiguration.class)
public class TemperaturePropertyListener implements ResourceChangeListener{

     private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void onChange(List<ResourceChange> changes) {
        for (final ResourceChange change : changes) {
            logger.info("**************************TemperaturePropertyListener******************change type**********************"+change.getType());
        }

    }


    @Activate
    @Modified
    public void activate(TemperatureListenerConfiguration config) {
        //config.getPaths();
        logger.info("**************************TemperaturePropertyListener******************activate**********************");
    }
}
```

The Interface

```
package com.aem.sites.interfaces;

import org.apache.sling.api.resource.observation.ResourceChangeListener;
import org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations.AttributeDefinition;
import org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations.AttributeType;
import org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations.ObjectClassDefinition;

@ObjectClassDefinition(name = "Temperature Listener Configuration")
public @interface TemperatureListenerConfiguration {

    @AttributeDefinition(
            name = ResourceChangeListener.PATHS,
            description = "Configurable paths for temperature event listener",
            type = AttributeType.STRING
            )
    String[] getPaths() default {"/content/aemsite/en/jcr:content/root/responsivegrid/banner"};

    @AttributeDefinition(
            name = ResourceChangeListener.CHANGES,
            description = "Event types",
            type = AttributeType.STRING
            )
    String[] getEventTypes() default  {"ADDED","REMOVED","CHANGED","PROVIDER_ADDED", "PROVIDER_REMOVED"};

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Javadoc for `org.apache.sling.api.SlingConstants` in sling 9 documentation here: http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling9/org/apache/sling/api/SlingConstants.html

it tells you specifically that `TOPIC_RESOURCE_ADDED` is deprecated:

> Deprecated. Register a [ResourceChangeListener](http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling9/org/apache/sling/api/resource/observation/ResourceChangeListener.html) instead

Read the documentation for `ResourceChangeListener`, additionally, you can take a look at a [sample SCR service impl](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-samples/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/samples/events/impl/SampleResourceChangeListener.java) from ACS Samples:

It should not be hard to convert that to R6 declarative service.

Also, here are two examples from the sling project [ResourceBackedPojoChangeMonitor](https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/4796414fb50956de3032cb498543324514df4e99/bundles/scripting/sightly/engine/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/scripting/sightly/impl/engine/ResourceBackedPojoChangeMonitor.java) and [OsgiObservationBridge](https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/b8b8d72c28a1f7116af7fdf0b1734283c6f199ff/bundles/resourceresolver/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/resourceresolver/impl/observation/OsgiObservationBridge.java)

Try to mimic those classes with the properties in the same class.

Comment: Thank you @Ahmed for the response. I have added the updated code. Can you please have a look at it and suggest any changes if you deem appropriate?

Comment: @user972418 Do you see issues? is it not working? it seems ok to me at first glance.

Comment: It's not throwing any errors and it is not working. One more thing I feel is that I have changed implementation by implementing ResourceChangeListener instead of EventHandler. One more question that I have now is when should I use Event Handler and when should I use Event Listener ? What difference does it make ? Sorry for too many questions.

Comment: Hi, sorry I do not have time to look at the code, I updated my answer with example resourceChangeListener from sling repo.

Comment: One more thing. On ResourceChange class, the methods getAddedPropertyNames() and a couple more have been deprecated. What do you suggest I should do in case I want to know the changed property on a node.

Comment: Your next option is a JCR EventListener here is an example: https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-samples/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/samples/events/impl/SampleJcrEventListener.java

Comment: Thanks again @Ahmed. It's funny they have a comment "NOTE: YOU ALMOST NEVER WANT TO USE JCR EVENT LISTENERS; USE SLING EVENT HANDLERS INSTEAD!" I will still use it though.